# iPhone NSDate setDay

Tags: iphone

Have a question. I'm working with NSDate and what i need is to get date that was 23 day before. How to do that ? I tried to to something like this:

```
        NSDate *date = [NSDate date];                          
        NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
        NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [calendar components:
            (NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | 
             NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit)
            fromDate:date];
    [dateComponents setDay:-23];
    [dateComponents setHour:0];
    [dateComponents setMinute:0];
    [dateComponents setSecond:0];
    date = [calendar dateFromComponents:dateComponents];
```

But its not works...ANy ideas ? thanks..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need to do is add an *NSTimeInterval* (which is in seconds) to a newly initialized *NSDate* instance.

The following code should do the trick:

```
NSDate* currentDate = [NSDate date];
NSTimeInterval = 60 * 60 * 24 * -23;
NSDate* twentyThreeDaysAgo = [currentDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:timeInterval];
```

Also note that *NSTimeInterval* is also just a typedef for a double (it's more readable).

There are alternative ways of producing the same effect. Be sure to check out the [NSDate class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
[dateComponents setDay:[dateComponents day] - 23];
```